# Disable "Would Like to Use Your Current Location" alert in iOS Phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation

I am developing a phonegap app, I removed all the plugins that uses the GPS. However, in iOS when I run my Phonegap app I get the following alert box after capturing a photo using the camera:

```
"..Would Like to Use Your Current Location"
```

Is there an option to entirely disable the Location based features so I won't get this arlt box anymore.

BTW: I've checked the `config.xml` file and the Geolocation plugin, Compass all removed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since the camera app uses the GPS to geotag the images there is not way to remove that warning.

Comment: There is a feature request to make collecting the location data optional: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4003

Answer (score -1):

[Please see the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024240/www-index-html-would-like-to-use-your-current-location-ionic-framework/45436897#45436897)

Add these lines in config.xml

i have fixed this problem.

Comment: I use apache cordova and i resolve that issue with that opinion. I put in my config.xml the code above:
"<feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="Geolocation" />
    </feature>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm"/>"

That resolve my issue! Thanks!