# www/index.html would like to use your current location - Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I searched various forums and posts related to GeoLocation based alert issue; For some reason no technique worked in my case.

Added "cordova-plugin-geolocation" plugin to my Ionic Framework Project.

Added to my base Controller under `$ionicPlatform.ready(...)`

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var coords = {};
    coords.updated = new Date();
    coords.latitude = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(6);
    coords.longitude = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);
    coords.altitude = position.coords.altitude + ' m';
    coords.accuracy = position.coords.accuracy + ' m';
    coords.altitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + ' m';
    coords.heading = position.coords.heading + '\u00b0';
    coords.speed = position.coords.speed + ' m/s';
    console.log('Fetched Location...' + geoText);
    return position;
}, function(err) {
    Logger.error(err.message);
}, {
    timeout: 10000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
});
```

When I emulate / run in iOS / Android it throws

> Error Message: /www/index.html would like to use Your Location

I would greatly appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: you can't really test cordova plugins in a device emulator. have you tried doing a build and installing it on a actual device? or you can use the intelxdk https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk import your project, then use the debug tab to push it to a device and have a live debugger in order to test the cordova plugin on a real device and be able to debug it.

Comment: Yes @Jess, I tried in my phone (both Android and iOS). Thanks for your reply. The plugin actually works fine, my concern here is that it pops up ".../Index.html Would like to use your location message" (apart from Application level confirmation).

Comment: yep we just started getting this issue in ios 8.4.1 not on android however. Did you ever manage to find a fix?

Comment: @JessPatton, kindly check my answer for solution

Comment: Okay I will give it a try.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by following this

Created a new Service for Location as follows

```
.service('LocationService', function($q) {
        this.fetch = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                deferred.notify('Fetching Location...')
                var coords = {};
                coords.updated = new Date();
                coords.latitude = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(6);
                coords.longitude = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);
                coords.altitude = position.coords.altitude + ' m';
                coords.accuracy = position.coords.accuracy + ' m';
                coords.altitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + ' m';
                coords.heading = position.coords.heading + '\u00b0';
                coords.speed = position.coords.speed + ' m/s';
                deferred.resolve(position);
            }, function(err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }, {
                timeout: 10000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    })
```

Then we shall call services as

```
Location.fetch().then(function(pos){...})
```

within `$ionicPlatform.ready(..)` or add to a button `ng-click` to fetch location.

**Root Cause:**
What I believe is that when we call `Location.fetch()` or `navigator.geolocation..` directly in any controllers, its executed when the controllers are loaded initially. This might get fired before Cordova / Ionic platform is ready and hence we get the additional / unwanted alert mentioning that www/index.html is trying to use location as my problem states.

Comment: yep this fixed the problem on ios.

Comment: Can you share your import statement for Location? And how is ".service" attached to Location?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in config.xml

i have fixed this problem.

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="Geolocation" />
</feature>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm"/>
```

Comment: Where does the config.xml file sit?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
//imports
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

//constructor
private ptf: Platform

//function get location
this.ptf.ready().then(()=> {
GET LOCATION HERE
//this.getGeo();
})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).