# Mapbox location request prompt in ios ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, permissions, geolocation, mapbox

I have a React app that I'm turning into a phone app with Ionic and capcitorjs. A mapbox map is a big part of the app and when you open the app, it requests permission to access the phone's location with a pretty normal prompt. This is fine, and the map centers on the user properly (using @capacitor/geolocation) when the app is opened. But when the user pushes the mapboxgl.GeolocateControl button that centers on the user and adds the blue location dot, the prompt is strange and I don't see where to change it. The prompt to use the user's location (despite already having permission) is:

> "://" Would Like To Use Your Current Location
>
> Don't Allow | Ok

Where can I change this prompt? It does not appear on Android so this is only an iOS problem. For the first prompt to request geolocation access, that is editable in the Info.plist file in XCode, but this "Would Like..." prompt doesn't even appear in the Info.plist. It seems to be caused by mapbox. Can the prompt be changed with @capacitor/geolocation?

Here are the relevant dependencies for this npm app:

```
"ionic": "^5.4.16",
"mapbox-gl": "^2.5.1",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.2.4",
"@capacitor/geolocation": "^1.1.0",
"@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.13.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"@capacitor/android": "^3.2.4",
"@capacitor/app": "^1.0.3",
"@capacitor/cli": "^3.2.4",
"@capacitor/ios": "^3.2.4",
```

Comment: There is this similar question, but it is using cordova, is a bit old, and is difficult to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024240/www-index-html-would-like-to-use-your-current-location-ionic-framework

Comment: hey check out my answer and confirm me is it working for you or not ? if the issue is same you can mark my answer correct , thanks

Answer (score -1):

ios has two type of geo location permissions

1. one time use location permission (next time it will again ask for permission)
2. when app use (it requires when app is running mode)
   the third permission is always which not allowed in ios 12

**Solution :**

in xcode info.plist add these two properties

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

and some text in there string value

Comment: These are already in my imo.plist file but they do not control the second permission request I'm getting.